# How to find GCP Persistent Disk Usage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-persistent-disk

I have a GCP Persistent Disk associated with a pod in a GKE cluster. How do I find the disk usage for the persistent disk ? Is there any GCP commands which will be help me find the disk usage ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Hello Prakash Premkumar, if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @DawidKruk Sorry for the delay. I have accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can use the **utilization** (percentage of used space) of a certain volume mount for a `Pod` with following metric:

- `kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization`

The description states:

> The fraction of the volume that is currently being used by the instance. This value cannot be greater than 1 as usage cannot exceed the total available volume space.

You can use this metric to monitor specific volume mounts that are backed by `Persistent Disk`.

> **Disclaimer!**
>
> Please remember that this method requires some tailoring to suit specific use cases. I've included an example below. I've also added a monitoring api query to extract the same information.

---

#### Using the `kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization` metric

Assuming that you have a `GKE` cluster with:

- 3 `PVC`'s that are backed by `PD`'s with `100GB` of space each
- 3 `Pods` where each of them is using single `PVC`

  - `ubuntu-ten` - where there is 10GB stored on mounted `PVC`
  - `ubuntu-twenty` - where there is 20GB stored on mounted `PVC`
  - `ubuntu-thirty` - where there is 30GB stored on mounted `PVC`

You can follow:

- `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Monitoring` -> `Metrics explorer`

[image: Volume utilization]

---

#### Querying the API

As asked in the comments under another answer:

> Is there any examples for the monitoring API to retrieve the disk usage?

Yes they are. You can query the monitoring API for data by using `MQL` (Monitoring Query Language).

You will need to have query from example used earlier (`volume_utilization`). You can extract such query by going into `Query Editor` (it's on last image).

```
fetch k8s_pod
| metric 'kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization'
| filter
    (resource.cluster_name == 'CLUSTER_NAME'
     && resource.pod_name =~ 'ubuntu.*')
    && (metric.volume_name == 'volume-data')
| group_by 1m, [value_utilization_mean: mean(value.utilization)]
| every 1m
```

To query the API you can use `Try this API` feature available in `GCP` documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Monitoring: API: Ref_v3: Rest: V3: Projects.timeseries: Query](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query)*

Query created with the help of this tool:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/PROJECT-NAME/timeSeries:query?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"fetch k8s_pod| metric '"'"'kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization'"'"'| filter(resource.cluster_name == '"'"'CLUSTER-NAME'"'"'&& resource.pod_name =~ '"'"'ubuntu.*'"'"')&& (metric.volume_name == '"'"'volume-data'"'"')| group_by 1m,[value_utilization_mean: mean(value.utilization)]| every 1m"}' \
  --compressed
```

In the response you should get the information about the utilization of volumes used by `Pods`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: Persistent Volume Claims](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#persistentvolumeclaims)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Dawid !

Comment: @PrakashPremkumar I've pointed the `kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization` metric as there is no other solution to check the taken space in `gce-pd` apart from mounting the volume to a `Pod` with `df`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the disk usage via a prepared command. But, you can check it via Stackdriver Monitoring (Google Cloud Operations Suite) with the metric named `container/disk/bytes_used`: [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-container). You can use Monitoring APIs if you need to automatize it.

Please notice that you must enable Stackdriver on your cluster before. If you haven't, follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing#migrating).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any examples for the monitoring API to retrieve the disk usage ?